# How do I get the NAME value from this array / stdClass Object / substring?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I have this array / stdClass Object / substring and I want to somehow get the NAME from it. It appears that the array field has what I'm guessing says how many attributes are in it, then says that each attribute is a string of X length. Is there an easy way to access this like a normal array item?

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
 (
 [id] => 4712
 [order_item_id] => 20657
 [inventory_id] => 585
 [product_id] => 21670
 [qty] => 3
 [subtotal] => 3
 [total] => 3
 [order_type] => 1
 [refund_qty] => 
 [refund_total] => 
 [reduced_stock] => 3
 [extra_data] => a:10:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Edmonton";s:3:"sku";s:14:"test-product-1";s:12:"supplier_sku";s:0:"";s:7:"barcode";s:0:"";s:8:"bbe_date";b:0;s:14:"inventory_date";s:16:"2023-02-22 19:06";s:3:"lot";s:0:"";s:6:"region";s:0:"";s:8:"location";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"273";}s:16:"expiry_threshold";i:0;}
 )
 [1] => stdClass Object
 (
 [id] => 4713
 [order_item_id] => 20657
 [inventory_id] => 583
 [product_id] => 21670
 [qty] => 2
 [subtotal] => 2
 [total] => 2
 [order_type] => 1
 [refund_qty] => 
 [refund_total] => 
 [reduced_stock] => 2
 [extra_data] => a:11:{s:4:"name";s:7:"Calgary";s:3:"sku";s:16:"test-product-1-1";s:12:"supplier_sku";s:0:"";s:7:"barcode";s:0:"";s:8:"bbe_date";b:0;s:14:"inventory_date";s:16:"2023-02-14 12:35";s:3:"lot";s:0:"";s:6:"region";s:0:"";s:8:"location";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"275";}s:16:"expiry_threshold";i:0;s:7:"is_main";s:3:"yes";}
 )
)
```

Need to know if there is an easy way to access an array / object field like this.

Comment: which `NAME` are you referring to and what have you tried thus far?

Comment: Do you mean somenthing like this? `unserialize($array[0]->extra_data)['name']`?

Comment: OMG THANK YOU GUYS! Yes you totally solved it, I just had to unserialize the data!!!! So much easier than doing a REGEX etc. Sorry if was duplicate question. You guys are awesome.